# Proper syntax for scrollTop / transform CSS effects in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

this is such a simple question that i'm almost embarrassed to post about it but i'm confused by the CSS transform syntax in the context of a jQuery script that calculates window height.

i have this code;

`$("#unambiguous-div").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 700);`

that works great for what it is. however instead of calculating the opacity, i'd rather it do a `transform: scale(0.xxxx);`. i'm not sure where to the correctly place the `scale` part, as the CSS syntax already has parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#unambiguous-div").css("transform", "scale(" + (1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 700) + ")");
```

or with the ES6 template literal syntax

```
$("#unambiguous-div").css("transform", `scale(${1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 700})`);
```